# how do i archive emails in Kmail

Tags: kde, kmail

i'm using gmail IMAP through kmail.
i want to archive the emails, the way gmail does.
is it even possible through kmail?

Comment: What do you mean "the way gmail does"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS Outlook I can move messages from the inbox to a folder called "All Mail", which has the effect of archiving the message.  You may need to subscribe to the All Mail folder in Kmail.

Comment: will try it, seems to be the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to create an action to do that, copied verbatim from [this blog post](http://jussi01.com/2012/11/20/archiving-on-kmail/):

> 1. go to Kmail (inside or outside of Kontact, doesnt matter).
> 2. go to Settings -> Configure Filters
> 3. Click the new filter button on the left, give your filter a name (this will appear on the shortcut also, I simply used "Archive")
> 4. Under filter criteria, choose "match all messages"
> 5. Under filter actions, choose "move into folder" and select the folder you want to archive to.
> 6. Under the advanced tab, *uncheck* the "apply this filter to incoming messages"
> 7. Then check the "Apply this filter on manual filtering", "add this filter to the apply menu" and "additionally add this filter to the toolbar".
> 8. Set the shortcut using the button provided (I used "q" because it didnt conflict with anything else)
> 9. Choose an Icon for the shortcut menu
> 10. Click apply/OK and you are Done!

The author says he got it from channel `#kontact` on freenode IRC.

Where it says "5. ... select the folder you want to archive to", you should choose `{your account}/[Gmail]/All Mail`.

The downside is that if you have more than one Gmail account configured, you'll have to create one filter for each, with a different destination folder.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this functionality was already present in 2009 or not, but the way to do this now is as follows:

1. Settings > Configure KMail... > Accounts > [select an IMAP account] > Modify > Archive Folder [tab]
2. Enable; select folder; choose archiving type (‘Unique’ for GMail-like case)
3. Repeat the above for any IMAP account you want (folder can be different)
4. Settings > Configure Shortcuts...
5. Add a shortcut of your choice to ‘Archive’

So there is no need to create filters and a single shortcut suffices.